# meaning of "everything that it means to be"

Tags: meaning

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/T-HGdc8L-7w?t=240)

> The class, which is a new block of code
> that I'm going to ask you to write
> if you choose to follow these tutorials,
> is this idea of encapsulate.
> everything that goes in between the open curly
> bracket and the closed curly bracket
> is **everything that it means to be** a bubble.

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2011&smoothing=3&content=it%20means%20to%20be&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&corpus=15&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cit%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20Means%20to%20Be%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cit%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20means%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20Means%20to%20Be%3B%2Cc0), similar use would be

> 1001 Things It Means to Be a Dad

I guess it means that the characteristics one must have to claim they are some specific type of group of people or something.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's right. It's the answer to the question "What does it mean to be a dad?", and the implication is that if one lacks one of the 1001 things, then one isn't quite a "dad".

In the case of the "bubble", the chosen name of a new Javascript class, the word "everything" can be used because that's a much simpler thing - just the data and the functions or methods associated with that class. Every instantiation of that class will have the same kind of data and the same methods.